# I tried substituting some values of $x$. I also know that $f(x)=x$ is a solution to the function but I am just not able to systematically prove it.

Tags: functional-equations

Solve the functional equation $f(x+1)+f(x-1)=2f(x)$ for $f(x)$

I tried substituting for $x= x-1; x-2; x+1;x+2$

But I can't seem to get to a systematic method to solve this question.

I do know that $ f(x)=x $ works but can't prove it.

Comment: It's easy to prove $f(x)=x$ is a solution, since $x+1+x-1=2x$. Similarly, $f(x)=ax$ is also a solution for any value of $a$

Comment: $f(x) = ax + b + g(x)$ works, where $g$ is any function that is periodic with period $1$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have more condition on f (continuity, derivability, convexity...), you will have a lot of possibilities...

With no more assomption, using usual sequences theories with linear recurrent condition (I only have the [french](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_r%C3%A9currente_lin%C3%A9aire) reference), we can say that there exist two fonction g,h (with no condition on it) such that, if we note E(x) the greatest natural number smaller than x and {x}=$x-E(x) \in [0,1[$ the fractional part of x, we have : $$f(x)=g(\{x\})+h(\{x\})E(x)$$
To see that, consider the sequences $a_n=f(\{x\}+n)$, and note that the hypothesis become $a_{n+1}-2a_n+a_{n-1}=0$, and then use the theory (here 1 is a double zero of the caracteristic polynome)

Another way to state this result (via some manipulation) is to say that  there is two 1-periodic fonction k,l such that $$f(x)=k(x)+l(x)*x$$

We can then take such a fonction, and check that the equation is valid.
I don't think we can do better than that without more hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f$ is $C^2$ then Taylor's Theorem shows that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h}=cf''(x),$$where $c$ is $1/2$ or $1$ or $2$ or something, I never recall the constant without working it out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't prove whether or not there are extra solutions, so here's a partial answer:

Let $a$ be any real number and $f(x)=ax$

Now $f(x+1) + f(x-1) = a(x+1) + a(x-1) = ax + a +ax - a = 2ax = 2f(x)$

Therefore, $f(x)=ax$ is always a solution to the equation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming continuity, we have, $$\frac {f(x+1)+f(x-1)}{2}=f\left(\frac {(x+1)+(x-1)}{2}\right)$$
Hence, from the equality condition of Jensen's inequality, it is clear that $f''(x)=0$ which means $f(x)$ is linear. Substitute $f(x)=ax+b$, you'll get $b=0$, and $a\in R$.

Comment: Well I didn't actually learn Jensen's inequality yet, but thanks for the help.